# Function for summing the dictionaries in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Every loop in this function:

```
def sum_total(files, local_dir):
    final_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(files)):
        with open(local_dir+files[i], 'r') as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            res = find_by_tag(data)
            print('res: ', res)
            sum_values_from_several_dict_to_one(res)
```

Generates example output:

```
{'Critical Tests': {'failed': 1, 'passed': 2, 'total': 5}, 'All Tests': {'failed': 5, 'passed': 0, 'total': 5}}
{'Critical Tests': {'failed': 2, 'passed': 3, 'total': 5}, 'All Tests': {'failed': 10, 'passed': 12, 'total': 12}}
{'Critical Tests': {'failed': 3, 'passed': 4, 'total': 5}, 'All Tests': {'failed': 10, 'passed': 0, 'total': 10}}
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

I would like to sum those values into one dictionary to get output like:

```
{'Critical Tests': {'failed': 6, 'passed': 9, 'total': 15}, 'All Tests': {'failed': 25, 'passed': 12, 'total': 27}}
```

The problem is - how should the 'sum_values_from_several_dict_to_one' function looks like? Thats my code but it does not work.. What should be improved?

```
def sum_values_from_several_dict_to_one(d1):
   final_dict = {}
   for d in d1 <?>:
    for test, results in d.items():
        if test not in final_dict:
            final_dict[test] = {}
        for key, value in results.items():
            if key in final_dict[test]:
                final_dict[test][results] += value
            else:
                final_dict[test][key] = value
   return final_dict
```

Comment: What is your current output? And should not Critical Tests be 15 instead of 5? And why All Tests failed is 20 and not 25(the total of the 3)

Comment: @SandraK, expected output is mentioned above, current output is last 'res' value

Comment: @kk_pl: in you desired output, under 'All Tests', you have a sum of 20? shouldn't it be 25 instead? It's pretty unclear to me what you want ...

Comment: @SandraK. Yes, it should be 25. Now is ok. I just want to sum 'res' values from sum_total function into one dictionary to get expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have:

```
a = {'Critical Tests': {'failed': 1, 'passed': 2, 'total': 5}, 'All Tests': {'failed': 5, 'passed': 0, 'total': 5}}
b = {'Critical Tests': {'failed': 2, 'passed': 3, 'total': 5}, 'All Tests': {'failed': 10, 'passed': 12, 'total': 12}}


def sum_dicts (dict1, dict2):
    res = {}
    for key, val in dict1.items():
        for k, v in dict2.items():
            if k == key:
                if type(val) is dict:
                    res.update({key: sum_dicts(val, v)})
                else:
                    res.update({key: val + v})
                break
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sol = sum_dicts(a, b)
    print(sol)
```

Output:

`{'All Tests': {'failed': 15, 'total': 17, 'passed': 12}, 'Critical Tests': {'failed': 3, 'total': 10, 'passed': 5}}`

EDIT:

Assuming `res` is a dict you can use it like this:

```
def sum_total(files, local_dir):
    final_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(files)):
        with open(local_dir+files[i], 'r') as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            res = find_by_tag(data)
            print('res: ', res)
            final_dict = sum_dicts(final_dict, res)
```

Comment: You just summed two dictionaries. The problem is that the dictionary is changing inside the loop, and every loop should add dictionary values to the values from the next loop
Just look at my 'sum_total' and tell me how to sum 'res' values

Comment: I'll edit it the answer but it's basically calling the same function with the next dict.

Comment: What data structure is `res`?? A list of dicts?

Comment: Its just a dict. By printing `res` you generate 'example output' mentioned above

Comment: Check the edit and let me know. It's pretty straightforward. Just calling `final_dict = sum_dicts(final_dict, res)` inside the loop.

Comment: It does not work that way. (output of final_dict gives nothing) Look at the `res`:
`{'Critical Tests': {'failed': 3, 'passed': 4, 'total': 5}, 'All Tests': {'failed': 10, 'passed': 0, 'total': 10}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165930/discussion-between-epinal-and-kk-pl).

Comment: Ok. Its works now. I figured it out. I have changed the calling of the function for the way you did it, and made little changes in my function. Thanks a lot!